# Cloud Flow Designer does not show Lightning Component that implements lightning:availableForFlowScreens

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, spring18

The documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens.htm says that if a Lightning Component implements lightning:availableForFlowScreens it should be visible in the Cloud Flow Designer, but it isn't.

This is the component:

```
<aura:component description="FlowCmp1" implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">

    Oh haiii

    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.doTheThing}"/>

</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    doTheThing : function(component){
        var navigate = component.get("v.navigateFlow");
        navigate("NEXT");
    }
})
```

Pls help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait, never mind! I've got it working. There were two things I hadn't done:

- Go to Process Automation settings and check 'Enable Lightning Runtime for Flows'
- I was looking at the wrong part of the designer - I assumed it would be part of the main palette but its one of the fields you can add under a Screen. I am a total goose.